# Manually run macro in powerpoint presenter view

Tags: vba, powerpoint

**TLDR: Can't run macros from powerpoint presenter view.** If you're not interested in the background, just skip right to "What is not working".

---

I've painstakingly created some macros that I want to run from within the powerpoint presenter view. The macros work, but I'm stuck on the 'run from presenter view' part.

What I have:

- I have a .pptm file, called *the toolbox*. The toolbox is where all my custom macros live that are not specific to any one powerpoint file; that includes the macros I am talking about here. The powerpoint file that the toolbox macros are working on is called *the target*.

  (Why do it like this you ask? Because that way, I can use the toolbox macros in *any* target file without having to copy them over, always as long as I have the toolbox open alongside it. That way, (1) no versioning problems and (2) no copy-paste hassle and (3) not turning every pptx into a pptm file and (4) not having to remove all code when sending the file to someone. I've adopted this strategy in Excel and it's fantastic; highly recommended.)

What I want:

- I want to be able to run the toolbox macros when presenting *any* powerpoint slideshow in presenter mode (it's already working when in 'edit mode'). I want to to be able to do this...

  1. ...*without having to make changes to the target*. Changes like: binding macros to slide transitions or to the click-event of newly added shapes. That's because the toolbox won't always be around when using the target.
  2. ...*without installing 3rd party addins to the powerpoint software*. I'm not able to install these, as I'm not always presenting on my own hardware.

What is working:

- The macros work when I `alt-tab`, from the presenter mode, into the VBA Editor, put the cursor within the macro body, and press `F5`.
- They also show up when I press `alt-F8` ('run macro' window) when I'm not in presenter mode.

What is not working:

- I can't bind the macros to keys like is possible in Word (`Keybind` if I remember correctly) or Excel (`Application.OnKey`). Why this isn't harmonised across these products is beyond me, but I've learnt this is not possible in Powerpoint, so let's forget about this possibility.
- I also can't get the 'run macro' window to appear with its `alt-F8` shortcut from within the presenter view. Does anyone know how to do this?
- As a third try, I've bound the macros to `alt, 3`, `alt, 4`, etc. in the quick access toolbar. But this also seems to only work when not in presenter mode.

I'm currently wondering **how macros are supposed to be manually (i.e., not event-triggered) run while giving a presentation** at all. There seems no way to get to them...

Many thanks

---

Full disclosure: I'd created this same [question](https://superuser.com/q/1552849/567543) on Superuser, but it wasn't getting much views, so I decided to add it here as well.

Comment: Here are a couple of add-ins that allow you to generate custom keyboard shortcuts. The first explicitly says you can create shortcuts for macros: http://officeoneonline.com/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html https://pptproductivity.com/powerpoint-add-shortcut-keys

Comment: Thanks John, it seems the first link would indeed accomplish what I want to do. However, these addins are not free, and more importantly, I don't want to have to ask for permission of the device owners to install 3rd party software whenever I give a presentation somewhere. Maybe I should have mentioned that in my question; I'm looking for a self-contained solution that can 'fit' into one pptm-file.

Comment: I've added more information about my use case.